# "No overload matches this call" when assigning values to a map that uses provider token with interface as T - typescript

Tags: typescript, dictionary, generics, interface

I have a simple Map:

```
public static servicesMap: Map<string, ProviderToken<IGenericService>> = new Map([
        ['FirstService', FirstService],
        ['SecondService', SecondService]
    ]);
```

I use this map for injecting the correct service based on a passed string. It was working well when only FirstService was in the map. The moment I tried to add the second one I got the overload error along with 4 iterator errors for example:

```
"Argument of type '([string, typeof FirstService] | [string, typeof SecondService])[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<readonly [string, typeof FirstService]>"
```

Pretty much comes down to the error:

```
"Type 'typeof SecondService' is not assignable to type 'typeof FirstService'"
```

Both services implement IGenericService interface so why is it a problem of type and how can I fix it or go around it?
Edit: I've added all the classes definitions and how I use them for clarity. Each class is of course in it's own file.

```
export interface IGenericService {
  serviceType: string;
  getData(id: number): void;
  saveData(id: number, productName: string): void;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirstService implements IGenericService {
  serviceType: string = 'FirstService';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getData(id: number): void {
    throw new Error('not implemented');
  }

  saveData(id: number, productName: string) {
    throw new Error('not implemented');
  }
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SecondService implements IGenericService {
  serviceType: string = 'SecondService';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getData(id: number): void {
    throw new Error('not implemented');
  }

  saveData(id: number, productName: string) {
    throw new Error('not implemented');
  }
}

export class ServicesMapping {
  public static servicesMap: Map<string, ProviderToken<IGenericService>> = new Map([
            ['FirstService', FirstService],
            ['SecondService', SecondService]
        ]);
}

export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public service!: IGenericService;
  @Input() serviceName!: string;

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const serviceType = ServicesMapping.servicesMap.get(this.serviceName);
    if(serviceType != undefined) this.service = this.injector.get<IGenericService>(serviceType);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, with all of the types defined, so we don't have to guess at them. A great way to do that is to make sure your example is complete in [the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play). (But also be sure to put the code **in** the question, don't just include a playground link. Also, be aware of [this long-standing SO bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386543/why-does-my-typescript-playground-link-break-when-i-use-insert-hyperlink) when posting playground links; there's a workaround there.)

Comment: You've said the services implement `IGenericService`, but the map isn't `Map<string, IGenericService>`, it's `Map<string, ProviderToken<IGenericService>>`...?

Comment: What is `@Injectable`? `HttpClient`? `ProviderToken`? `OnInit`? `OnDestroy`?You haven't tagged anything that tell us what libs you're using, and it's not a good idea to make us guess.

Comment: The code has `consturctor` instead of `constructor`. Please don't *retype* code, it leads to typos and other errors. Use **copy and paste** to show us the necessary code. Additionally, adding things that will break compilation like `...and so on` isn't useful. Your goal is to make something we copy, paste, and help you with.

Comment: I've updated the main post with my classes and their usage. Yeah I am returning ProviderToken because that's what I need for my injector.get to work. I thought that by setting ProviderToken<T> where T will be an interface implemented by both services I would be able to return any service class no problem. It's my first time using ProviderToken and it does work when there is only a single value in the map

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I understand but does it matter what is the exact implementation of the service in this case? It could be throw new Error('Not implemented') as well. My issue isn't really with the services not working but with the Map itself not allowing me to add another value.

Comment: Then reduce the problem to a [mre] that doesn't involve all this extra stuff, if all this extra stuff isn't necessary to replicate the problem. I'm trying to help you, but to do so, first I have to replicate the problem, and I can't replicate it with the information you've provided because there's too much missing (and too much extraneous, unneeded things that are undefined as well -- we could just ignore those if they weren't undefined, but for instance `ProviderToken` is fundamental to the type of the map).